# modify image contrast

Tags: image-transforms

In my experience is the build-in process of image transform not too kind to the image quality, even with the highest quality. In my case the brighter tones in the images are lost which means that images have no properly defined edges.
Is there a good possibility to modify images troughout so they don't drop to total white?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know which image driver your instance is using? GD or Imagick? If GD, try changing the driver first to see if that's the case.

Comment: +1 to this. Imagick typically produces better image quality output and supports a wider ranger of image formats.  Craft will use it automatically if it sees it's available on the server.

Comment: ImageMagick is being used. Is there a way to modify the contrast curve of the images?

Comment: You can create a module that makes use of Imagick's photo altering features.